# Best way to count and filter Bing Custom Search results by site slice

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing, bing-api

I'm using the Search API to search in a Bing Custom Search instance. I defined one URL - also known as "slice" in the documentation - for my main site and additional URLs that are subparts of it, boosted up at various levels.

In my results page, I'd like to add filter functionality with filter criteria that match site slices.

- Is it a legit approach to reference both a parent domain and subsites of it in the same search instance?
- Is there a way to break up search results by slice with the API? I.e. for each result to be able to know which slice it originates from, and ideally to have aggregated numbers (e.g. result count) by slice?
- Can I query on a specific slice or do I have to create a dedicated search instance with only that slice in it?

Answer (score -1):

All domain related subsites can be in same instance. Pinned feature is used to filter search result for a specific query from a specific URL in the site. Please refer below link,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/tutorials/custom-search-web-page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future!

Comment: According to the doc, pinning doesn't *filter* results. It moves pinned web pages to the top of search results.